# BootStrap css Stacked to horizontal not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am practicing Bootstrap from this [link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic) by seeing examples.I tried to get the same output as per the example given but I get only simple lines.This is piece of code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Prices for todo app</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="bootstrap-3.0.0/assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="bootstrap-3.0.0/assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<a class="btn" data-controls-modal="my-modal" data-backdrop="true" >Launch Modal</a>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
</div>
</div>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
  $('#my-modal').modal({
  show:true,
  closeOnEscape: true
});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What things did i miss?
here is the screenshot of the output
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "simple lines"? can you post an screenshot of your issue?

Comment: Your markup is correct, my guess is there's an issue with your CSS files, what is that custom.css?

Comment: @koala_dev I was doing some examples so i am only changing the body part.Earlier I was practicing for modal part,now for grid part.Leaving the head i am just changing the body.custom.css was already there when I downloaded bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the bootstrap CSS files saved to the appropriate directory on your computer. They need to be located in the same folder as your HTML file, but following this path from that point: `"bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/css/..."`

You can find these CSS files along with the other stuff that you downloaded from the Bootstrap website.

Edit: Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating the use of the grid in Bootstrap: http://jsfiddle.net/EELqA/

Comment: yes its there already,I think you are refering to this **bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css** and this path is valid

Comment: I have checked in google chrome console and its not showing any error,suppose if the path is invalid then it should an error.Moreover only this part is not showing properly rest of all the code are working fine

Comment: Hrm... so the rest of the Bootstrap code is working correctly? Is the Modal working?

Comment: As i said I have posted only a part of the code.In the full code modal is working.Can you give me working example for this[link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic)

Comment: Take a look at my JSFiddle here (edited main post as well): http://jsfiddle.net/EELqA/

Comment: @cardem +1 for your help.Also from where did you get this codes from internet or you have done it on your own.I wanted to learn bootstrap but finding difficulty in the bootstrap site.Which other sites will you recommend.

Comment: @javaBeginner the javascript code in the fiddle is just a copy-paste of bootstrap.js file, the contents were taken from this page http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: @koala_dev is it required javascript file.In the jsfiddle cardern has given even if i remove the javascript then also its working.

Comment: @javaBeginner no it's not required, it's the same javascript file that you have included in you project, it contains the code for the multiple Bootstrap Javascript plugins, nothing to do with the grid system which is pure CSS

Comment: where to get the source codes of the link you have given http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: @javaBeginner just use the "view source" option in your browser or use Ctrl+U shortcut in chrome

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css style in your own css file, and use it in class="row show-grid"

```
.show-grid [class^="col-"] {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: rgba(86,61,124,.15);
  border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and searched every where.
But After 2hours of struggling came to know that BootStrap css Stacked to horizontal is not working in IE-10 compatibility mode. 
Its a compatibility issue